# Cannot log off or shutdown in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: xfce

Hey just installed XFCE on my Ubuntu 10.10 machine. But now I cannot log off or shutdown my computer. When I click on `Log off` or `Shutdown` nothing happens! If I again click on them a dialog box appears saying that :

```
Failed to receive a reply from the session manager

Session manager must be in idle state when requesting a shutdown
```

So how to fix this issue??

Comment: which session manager are your system using? gdm or lightdm?

Comment: I am using GDM as a session manager...

Comment: reinstall gdm from synaptic manger or command line

Comment: Still no luck! Reinstalled GDM but the same error message appears again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here is the link :

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1948916.

Thanks all for replying and answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try `sudo shutdown -h now` from your terminal.

Comment: Do I always have to use this command? Can you tell another fix or why this is happening?

Comment: Are there any other processes running while you are attempting to shut down the machine? If you want to restart, there is another instance of `shutdown` you can use ctrl+alt+T `sudo shutdown -r now`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem simply because the ownership of the the $HOME directory was improperly set to root. It seems that the user must be able to write an an xfce4-session-* file to ~/.cache/sessions/. So attempts to shut down fail if this file is not present.