# Session manager must be in idle state when requesting a shutdown

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown, session, logout

This is the error message I get when trying to logout or shutdown from the menu in Xubuntu 16.04 on my Dell laptop.

Interestingly when I choose "Log Out..." from the actions menu the first time nothing happens, but if I try it again then do I get the `Session manager must be in idle state when requesting a shutdown` error dialog.

I have tried the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116990/cannot-log-off-or-shutdown-in-ubuntu-10-10#) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727752/shutdown-problem) and some others from google to no avail.

I am able to shutdown by running `sudo shutdown now` from the terminal.

Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10 fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm having this same issue with a fresh install of 17.04. Although my home directory is from older versions.

Comment: @deltaray I had this issue in Xubuntu 18.04 after removing some packages (by ` sudo aptitude purge ~o`). Reinstalling nvidia driver in "Additional Drivers" tab in "Software & Updates" dialog fixed it.

Comment: problem still exists in 18.04

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happend with me today, it was the first time:

I've decided to go to the terminal mode by ctrl+alt+f1 and then find out the process id of session manager, by 'pidof  xfce-session' then close it with 'kill -9 ID'.
Then it started working fine.